# Binomial Newton complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I am really struggling with this.
Given the next binomial Newton:

[if (1+z)^n=(C0^n)+(C1^n)z+(C2^n)z^2+(C3^n)z^3+...+(Cn^n)z^n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kag2.png)

and taking z=1,w1,w2 where wk=-1/2+(sqrt(3)/2)i,k=1.Find the next sums formulas:

[a)(C0^n)+(C3^n)+(C6^n)+...
b)(C1^n)+(C4^n)+(C7^n)+...
c)(C2^n)+(C5^n)+(C8^n)+...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUoLy.png)

To be honest, i have no idea of where to start from. I would appreciate some help. Thank you guys!

Comment: Please format your question.  Hard to read.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

$1$, $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are cube roots of $1$, with $\omega_1^2 = \omega_2$ and $\omega_2^2 = \omega_1$.
You should get

$$ \eqalign{
     2^n &= C^n_0 + C^n_1 + C^n_2  + C^n_3 + \ldots + C^n_n = (a) + (b) + (c)\cr
(1+\omega_1)^n &= C^n_0 + C^n_1 \omega_1 + C^n_2 \omega_2 + C^n_3 + \ldots + C^n_n \omega_1^n = (a) + \omega_1 (b) + \omega_2 (c)\cr
(1+\omega_2)^n &= C^n_0 + C^n_1 \omega_2 + C^n_2 \omega_1 + C^n_3 + \ldots + C^n_n \omega_2^n = (a) + \omega_2 (b) + \omega_1 (c)\cr}$$
You should then be able to find $(a)$, $(b)$ and $(c)$ as appropriate combinations of
$2^n$, $(1+\omega_1)^n$ and $(1+\omega_2)^n$.  For this it is helpful to note
that $1 + \omega_1 + \omega_2 = 0$.